# Validar formulario de mailchimp antes de enviar

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Tengo un formulario de Mailchimp y en los respectivos `input` tengo el atributo `required` pero cuando pulso enviar en el formulario me manda a la página de validación de errores de Mailchimp y no me gusta que ocurra ese problema.

Me gustaría que saliera el mensaje tipico de HTML5 de "completa este campo", no sé si tiene que ver estrictamente con el formulario de Mailchimp generado desde su página o puedo cambiar algo en mi HTML

les dejo el código del formulario.

html

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="Contact-form">
        <form action="//toncandigital.us13.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=8a3c37fbd77ba8932cd9f1252&amp;id=ea21260d99" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
         <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
         <div class="mc-field-group">
            <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="Contact-input " id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="Nombre" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="Contact-input " id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Apellido" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="Contact-input required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com*" required>
        </div>
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_f5094e5fb00e00f72d45453f8_442a8b9d87" tabindex="-1" value="">    </div>
            <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Suscríbeme" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="Contact-input btn"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar este trozo de código que normalmente utilizo del lado del front-end

```
$("#enviar_datos").click(function(e){
     var nombre = $("#name").val();
     var correo = $("#email").val();
     var div_error = $("#error");
     var formulario = $("#form-reg");

    if(nombre == "" || correo == "" ||  (correo.indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || correo.indexOf('.', 0) == -1)){
        if(nombre == ""){
           div_error.html("<p>Te falta registrar tu nombre</p>");
           div_error.show();
           return false;
        }else if(correo == ""){
           div_error.html("<p>Te falta registrar tu correo</p>");
           div_error.show();
           return false;
           }else{
              div_error.html("<p>El correo introducido no es correcto</p>");
              div_error.show();
              return false;
        }
    }else if(div_error.is(":visible") && nombre != "" && correo != ""){                    
        div_error.hide();
        return true;   
    }
 });
```

Donde:

```
    <form id = "form-reg" action="">
       <input type="text" id="name" name=""/>
       <input type="text" id="email" name=""/>
       <div id="error" class="error"></div>
       <button type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar_datos">enviar</button>
   </form>
```